# Writing data into a file when using repmat in matlab

Tags: matlab, printf

I have a set of data that I generate by using:

```
repmat x=5; y=[repmat(x, 1, 5)];
fn=fopen('A.txt', 'w');
fprintf(fn, '%g\t%g\t%g\t%g\t%g\t\r\n', y)
```

How do I set it up so that I do not have to type in `%g\t` as many times as I am using in the `repmat`.

Thanks for any inputs.

Answer (score 0):

try the following to generate your format string on the fly if you don't want the number of %g\t hard coded

```
  fstring = '';
repeats=5;

for n=1:repeats
fstring=[fstring,'%g\t'];
end
fstring = [fstring,'\r\n'];

x=5;
y=[repmat(x, 1, repeats)];
fn=fopen('A.txt', 'w');
fprintf(fn, fstring, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
x=5; y=[repmat(x, 1, 5)];
save('A.txt', 'y' , '-ASCII');
```

Comment: save command just saves all variables from the current workspace and if filename exists, save overwrites the file. It saves the data as it is.

Or, you could just do (in your above code):

`x=5; y=[repmat(x, 1, 5)];
fn=fopen('A.txt', 'w');
fprintf(fn, '%g\t', y)`